# Monitor each folder as defined in an app.config

Tags: c#

I currently have a Windows Services which monitors one folder for new files being created.  The folder it monitors is defined in an app.config file as part of the solution as below.

```
<add key="WatchPath" value="C:\Temp\watch_directory\" />
<add key="MoveFilesPathA" value ="C:\Temp\watch_directory\" />
<add key="MoveFilesPathB" value ="C:\Temp\destination\" />
```

When I create a IO.FileWatcher instance Visual Studio creates the method for it and I create a IO.FileSystemEventArgs for it.

What I'm trying to achieve is being able to define multiple watch directories in the app.config.  What would be the best way to approach this?  I was thinking of a sort of for each 'watch-path' in app.config create required method and FileSystemEventArgs for it but I'm not entirely sure how to do that.  I imagine some sort of array/list?

Answer (score 1):

I generally write the folders in semicolon-separated and get all the folders with split method.

```
<add key="WatchPaths" 
     value="C:\Temp\watch_directory1\;C:\Temp\watch_directory2\" />

string[] paths = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WatchPaths"].Split(";");
```

Comment: This is actually **semicolon-separated** ..... a comma would be a `,` ....

Answer (score 0):

You can also make your own custom XML section like this:

```
<FoldersSection>
  <Folder Path="C:\Test"/>
  <Folder Path="C:\Test2"/>
</FoldersSection>
```

And then custom config section classes as explained [here](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2F2tw134k3%2528v%3Dvs.140%2529.aspx&ei=odm4VJ-lDaPuyQOWr4KQAQ&usg=AFQjCNFI9Hjyl9CxXxgw1IzfYEeJ1ajOww&bvm=bv.83829542,d.bGQ&cad=rjt)